# How to store sessions with PHP

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a PHP session class to store sessions.  What is the best way to deal with sessions?

This is what I have so far:

```
class Sessions {

    function start() {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['sid'] = randomstring();
        // insert session id into db
        // initialize user data
    }

    function destroy() {
        session_destroy();
        // delete sid from db too
    }

    function update() {
        session_regenerate_id();
        // update lastaccess time in db
    }
}
```

What is the best way to store sessions in PHP?

Comment: Just implement a class that **works** and **fits** all your requirements

Comment: Why do you need to store sessions in the db again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will answer your question of Session Handling? http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Storing-PHP-Sessions-in-a-Database/